# @current_page feature in Geb

Tags: groovy, geb

In `WATIR`we use `@current_page` whenever we lands to page which got created at run time (during test case execution).

I am looking for similar feature in `Geb`.

Here I have two Pages

**RegistrationPage.groovy**
where I have provided

`static url = "/register.html"`

I also have **UserProfilePage.groovy**

here I can't provide any `static url` because it gets created once I submit the Registration Page, it changes as per user name

example https://xxxxx.com/paul.html, if two paul's are there then https://xxxxx.com/paul2.html

I want to use

```
static content = {
        defaultprofilePic {$("#userprofilepic")}
    }
```

declared in `UserProfilePage.groovy`

If I am not using `to` keyword it would land me back to baseURL and if I use it gives exception that element not available on this page.

But I think if I use could something like @current_page it would pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `at(UserProfilePage)` which sets the current page to be an instance of `UserProfilePage` and also verifies its [at checker](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#at-checking).